# WiFi problem with Thinkpad 11e 5th gen

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, thinkpad

I had recently installed Ububntu 16.04 on Thinkpad 11e 5th gen but it does not work with the built in network card. However, usb D-link works. But when I upgraded the system it wouldn't work with the external card either.  I wonder whether 18.04 works better?
The output of lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list:
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2526] (rev 29)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0014]
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:506e]
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

Comment: 1. Try when booted live from a USB pendrive, 'Try Ubuntu'; 2. Are you talking about wired or wireless network? 3. Please specify *brand name and model* of the network cards.

Comment: Thank you. 1. I used live cd. If this works too I'll try your advise in august -- I travel currently. 2. I was talking about wireless. Didn't have a chance to try wired. 3. USB card is D-Link DWA - 125, what the PCI is I don't know.

Comment: It should work to boot from a live DVD too. I am no expert on wifi, but let us hope that wifi experts will see your question, and the more you can tell about the hardware, the better they can help. And I think it will help if you put 'wifi problem' into the title of your question. Good luck :-)

Comment: Thanks. Will add "wifi" wherever I can ;)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Pilot6 -- I did add that output -- see the initial post. The last two items there concern a usb D-Link card which works.